# split and merge pandas dataframe based on input column index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `test_df`. This dataframe contains 20 columns. I am given a list of column index `col_index = [3, 5]` for example.

I need to create two separate dataframes

- one only including the columns in col_index
- other includes all the columns except the columns in col_index

How do I do that?

I understand I can do

```
new_df = df.iloc[:, 3]
```

To create a dataframe out of column number 3. But what do I do as in this case I have multiple column numbers to separate out from the main dataframe?

Using python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `drop`

```
df1=df.iloc[:,col_index].copy()
df2=df.drop(df1.columns.tolist(),axis=1).copy()
```

Comment: depending on what you are doing with those df you might want to return df1 and df2 as copies, so you don't accidentally edit the main df, of which df1 and df2 are slices.

Comment: @Wen-Ben there is a small typo in the 1st line. If you correct that I will mark it as an answer. `df1=df.iloc[:,col_index].copy()`